# Split Time into hours with leading zero and minutes

Tags: r, time

How could I split the Time into hours with leading zero and minutes in below dataset. I tried sub with sprintf but didn't worked. Also tried str_sub and substr but couldn't get the desired output. Thanks.

dateorder <- structure(list(Date = c("30/04/2021", "30/04/2021", "30/04/2021", "30/04/2021", "30/04/2021", "30/04/2021", "30/04/2021", "30/04/2021", "30/04/2021", "30/04/2021"), Time = c(0L, 100L, 200L, 300L, 400L, 500L, 600L, 700L, 800L, 900L), Rainfall = c(0.4, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.8, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), Date_Formatted = structure(c(18747, 18747, 18747, 18747, 18747, 18747, 18747, 18747, 18747, 18747 ), class = "Date"), Intensity = c(0.4, 0, 0.2, 0.2, 0, 0.2, -1, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
sub("(\d{2})(\d{2})", "\1:\2",sprintf("%04d", dateorder$Time))
str_sub(dateorder$Time2,1,2)
substr(dateorder$Time2,start = 1, stop = 2)

```
# Expected output
# Hr mm
# 00 00
# 01 00
# 02 00
```

Comment: Could you please include the expected outcome in the question?

Comment: In your call to sub try `dateorder$Time` with an upper case T

Comment: @Peter - Thanks for pointing out the typo. This partly helped. I would like to split the Time column into 'Hrs' and 'mins' with a leading zero in front of hours for time between 0 to 9 hrs. Example 00, 01, 02,...09, 10, 11 for hrs and for mins double zero.

Comment: Thanks for this could you please edit the data in the question to include a few examples of the Time column with these cases so  that possible solutions can be tested and verified.

Comment: The data has not been changed, only the wording in the question. Please change the example data so that it includes expected variations of the `Time` column  for example how will the Time column display 00 hours:  "0000" or "00" how will the `Time`  column display `02 `hours: "0200" or "200"? And please include the expected output.

Comment: @Peter - Hope it makes a bit of sense now, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A base R option -

- `sprintf` adds a 0 as prefix if there is less than 4 digits in `Time` column.
- `strcapture` captures 1st 2 digits as hour (`hh`) and last 2 as minutes (`mm`).

```
strcapture('(\\d{2})(\\d{2})', sprintf('%04d', dateorder$Time), 
           proto = list(hh = character(), mm = character()))

#   hh mm
#1  00 00
#2  01 00
#3  02 00
#4  03 00
#5  04 00
#6  05 00
#7  06 00
#8  07 00
#9  08 00
#10 09 00
```

---

Using `tidyverse` -

```
library(tidyverse)

dateorder %>%
  mutate(Time = str_pad(Time, 4, pad = '0')) %>%
  extract(Time, c('hh', 'mm'), '(\\d{2})(\\d{2})')
```

Comment: @Ronal Shah - How could I get these two new columns alongside the other columns within the 'dateorder' table?

Comment: If you are using 1st option you can `cbind` `strcapture` output `dateorder <- cbind(dateorder, strcapture(....))` . For the 2nd option just assign the output back to `dateorder` i.e `dateorder <- dateorder %>% mutate(....`.

Comment: Thanks @Ronal Shah

Answer (score 0):

First using `strptime/strftime`, then `strsplit`.

```
tm <- strptime(paste(Sys.Date(), dateorder$Time), '%F %H%M') |> 
  strftime('%H:%M')
# [1] "10:00" "11:00" "12:00" "13:00" "14:00" "15:00" "16:00" "17:00" "18:00" "19:00"

cbind(dateorder, tm=do.call(rbind, strsplit(tm, ':')))
#           Date Time Rainfall Date_Formatted Intensity tm.1 tm.2
# 1  30/04/2021 1000      0.4     2021-04-30       0.4   10   00
# 2  30/04/2021 1100      0.4     2021-04-30       0.0   11   00
# 3  30/04/2021 1200      0.6     2021-04-30       0.2   12   00
# 4  30/04/2021 1300      0.8     2021-04-30       0.2   13   00
# 5  30/04/2021 1400      0.8     2021-04-30       0.0   14   00
# 6  30/04/2021 1500      1.0     2021-04-30       0.2   15   00
# 7  30/04/2021 1600      0.0     2021-04-30      -1.0   16   00
# 8  30/04/2021 1700      0.0     2021-04-30       0.0   17   00
# 9  30/04/2021 1800      0.0     2021-04-30       0.0   18   00
# 10 30/04/2021 1900      0.0     2021-04-30       0.0   19   00
```

*Note:* R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01).

Comment: Thanks, however, I couldn't make it to work. What does the |> does at the end of first line? I tried removing that as well.
Error in strsplit(tm, ":") : non-character argument

Comment: @AravindanKalai Your R version seems to be outdated, can you update it? Or do `strftime(strptime(paste(Sys.Date(), dateorder$Time), '%F %H%M'), '%H:%M')`